# CSS animation which move another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to do something like:

```
<div>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
<div>
```

And on start second is under the first. When I click second, first go under second, then if i click first - second goes under the first and so on. There are also animations (by css keyframes). I tried by + / ~ sign in css, but there is no - sign to affect first one. Tried changing classes, but animation run only one time.

How can I do it using only JS, CSS3? (I can't use JQuery, I am doing site as a course exercise and for that moment they told us not to use JQuery.

Is there a way to do this?

Full problem:

```
<article id="middle_field">
      <section id="firstPage">
      </section>
      <section id="secondPage">
      </section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
#middle_field section {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 85%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 3px #5c5b5b;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#firstPage {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
    margin-left: 20%;
    z-index: 16;
}
#secondPage {
    background: rgb(98, 98, 98, 0.9);
    margin-left: 25%;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}    
.deactivateFirstPage {
    animation: firstPageActivate 2s ease alternate forwards;
}
.deactivateSecondPage {
    animation: secondPageActivate 2s ease alternate forwards;
}
.activateFirstPage {
    animation: firstPageActivate 2s ease forwards;
}
.activateSecondPage {
    animation: secondPageActivate 2s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes firstPageActivate {
    0% {
        z-index: 15;
        top: 5%;
        margin-left: 20%;
        background: rgb(98, 98, 98, 0.9);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    1% {
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 5%;
        z-index: 16;
        top: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        cursor: default;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
        margin-left: 20%;
        z-index: 16;
        top: 0%;
    }
}
@keyframes secondPageActivate {
    0% {
        z-index: 15;
        top: 5%;
        margin-left: 25%;
        background: rgb(98, 98, 98, 0.9);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 45%;
        z-index: 16;
        top: 0;
    }
    100% {
        cursor: default;
        margin-left: 25%;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
        z-index: 16;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

With these classes that was second approach, when i tried to add it by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use pure JavaScript then you can do something like this:

```js
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

first.onclick = function() {
  first.style.zIndex = 0;
  second.style.zIndex = 1;
}

second.onclick = function() {
  second.style.zIndex = 0;
  first.style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

```css
#first {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't precise the question. I did it like you moment ago, and first animation work, but when i try to run animation on second, it doesn't work.

Comment: My JS:


const first = document.getElementById('firstPage');
const second = document.getElementById('secondPage');

first.onclick = function() {
  first.style.animation = 'firstPageActivate 2s ease forwards';
  second.style.animation = 'secondPageActivate 2s ease alternate forwards';
}

second.onclick = function() {
    first.style.animation = 'firstPageActivate 2s ease alternate forwards';
    second.style.animation = 'secondPageActivate 2s ease forwards';
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` and pseudo-class `:active`. An element with greater value of `z-index` is always in front of an element with a lower value. `:active` starts when user press mouse button down on element.

```css
.first{
  z-index: 50;
}
.second{
  z-index: 50;
}
.first:active{
  z-index: 100;
}
.second:active{
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precise the question, I want to run animation on these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I did it, if anyone is looking for an answer:

```
first.onclick = function() {
    first.style.animation = 'none';
    second.style.animation = 'none';
    first.offsetHeight;
    second.offsetHeight;
    first.style.animation = 'firstPageActivate 2s ease forwards';
    second.style.animation = 'secondPageActivate 2s ease reverse forwards';
}
second.onclick = function() {
    first.style.animation = 'none';
    second.style.animation = 'none';
    first.offsetHeight;
    second.offsetHeight;
    first.style.animation = 'firstPageActivate 2s ease reverse forwards';
    second.style.animation = 'secondPageActivate 2s ease forwards';
}
```